# Algorithm to calculate multiple integral.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, reference-request, multivariable-calculus

One of the major difficulties of student in advanced calculus  (including myself when student) is to obtain the extremes of repeated integrals to calculate the volume integral in $R^n$ *i.e.* transform  the integral 
$$
\int_{D}f(x) \,\mathrm d\,V_n, \quad  f\in C(\mathbb{R}^n)
$$
in the multiple integral 
$$
\int_{c_1^1}^{d_1^1}\cdots\int_{c_n^1}^{d_n^1} f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \,\mathrm d\,x_1\ldots \,\mathrm d\,x_n
+\ldots +
\int_{c_1^m}^{d_1^m}\cdots\int_{c_n^m}^{d_n^m} f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \,\mathrm d\,x_1\ldots \,\mathrm d\,x_n. 
$$
The integer $m$ arises from the need to partition the set $D$.

> More precisely I would get for a well-defined algorithm (that could be manually computable) whose output was the number $m\in\mathbb{N}$ and the extremes of integration in terms of vectors $a\in\mathbb{R}^p$, $b\in\mathbb{R}^p$ ​​and the matrices $M^1,\ldots,M^p\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ that define the set $D\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ as below
>   $$
> D=
> \left\{
> x=
> \left[
> \begin{array}{c}
> x_1 \\
> \vdots
> \\
> x_n
> \end{array}
> \right]
> \in\mathbb{R}^n\quad \left|\quad
> \begin{array}{c}
> a_1 \leq x^TM^1x \leq  b_1 \\
> \vdots\\
> a_p \leq x^TM^px \leq b_p \\
> \end{array}
> \right.
> \right\}
> \subset [-r,r]^n,\quad r>0.
> $$

In terms of explicit coordinates we have: $M^1=(M_{uv}^1)_{n\times n},\ldots ,M^p=(M_{uv}^p)_{n\times n}$ are the matrices  in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$  and  $a=(a_i)_p$ and $b=(b_j)_p$ are the vectors  in $\mathbb{R}^{p}$.

> **My question:** Is there any algorithm that can be implemented but it is computationally simple for calculate the extrems of repeated  integrals above? Some reference?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: computationally simple for computer or for human?

Comment: @Norbert For human.